Flux through a paraboloid in the first quadrant
The question is absolutely easy but I am unsure where I go wrong haha. I am given a vector field $\mathbf{u} = (y,z,x)$ and I need to find the ourward flux $\iint\limits_{M} \textbf{u} \cdot d\textbf{S}$ were $M$ is the paraboloid in the first quadrant $x^2 + y^2 +z = 1$.
My approach:
I think this is begging to use the divergence theorem and we see that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$ Now we close the surface with $z = 0$, $x = 0$, $y = 0$ planes. The easiest flux to compute is through the $xy$-plane as it is a quarter of a circle ($D$), the normal there is $\textbf{N}_1 = (0,0,-1)$ $$\iint\limits_{D} (-x) \, dx \, dy = -\frac{1}{3}$$
Now consider $x=0$ here the curve is $z = 1 - y^2$ and the normal $\textbf{N}_2 = (-1,0,0)$ hence the flux integral is $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y^2} (-y) \, dz \, dy = -\frac{1}{4}$$
Last surface is $y = 0$, $\textbf{N}_3 = (0,-1,0)$, $z = 1-x^2$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x^2} (-z) \, dz \, dx = -\frac{4}{15}$$
$$\iint\limits_{M} \textbf{u} \cdot d\textbf{S} = 0 + \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{15}\right) = \frac{13}{20}$$
The answer is $\frac{17}{20}$ Thank you for pointing out what I am doing wrong in this quite trivial question! :)

Apparently, I can't add fractions.. $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{15} = \frac{17}{20}$$ So the answer is correct...
